# How to draw onto Canvas leaving a trail? (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bitmap, android-canvas

I am programming a game and right now I am currently animating a sprite that is moving up and down the screen. After the sprite is drawn on screen, I am trying draw a permanent bitmap in place of where the animated sprite just was, sort of like a trail. However, I'm not sure how to permanently draw unto a Canvas or save the bitmap unto the canvas so it stays on screen when onDraw is updated. I want the character who is moving down the screen to leave a path behind him that is drawn from a bitmap. Is there any way to do this? I am programming using the Android SDK(Eclipse) with Java on Windows 7.

Comment: the trail will be another sprite

Comment: Yes the trail will be another sprite. Currently I have that sprite converted into a bitmap and being drawn but it's not behaving the way it's supposed to.

Comment: you should paint it just like the character, what's the problem?

Comment: Paint it just like the character? Are you referring to the paint object or a submethod for the type Canvas?

Comment: draw it like the character, sorry. in your onDraw. It's no difference if you draw a character or a trail!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still a little confused by "draw it like a character". If the sprite is loaded as a Bitmap then the Bitmap is drawn on the Canvas by canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap). Is there another way to draw a Bitmap?

Comment: that one's perfect. So for your trail, you should do the same: canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapSprite, x, y); canvas.drawBitmap(trailSprite,x+trailOffset, y+trailOffsetY);

Comment: What is drawn doesn't stay permanently on screen however. I am trying to get it so that the entire trail is being shown on screen. The trail needs to be like paintbrush where that when it follows the sprite animating down the screen it leaves a path or trail that is static and doesn't go away.

Comment: that's why you have to paint it separately! Nothing you do on onDraw is permanent. You have to paint the trails every frame, just like you do with normal characters. Maybe you need to draw them as Paths (lines that you can add sections to) if they are very long, kind of snakes game. But either way, you'd need to do it every frame!

Comment: If I'm drawing it every frame to make it permanent, doesn't that mean that I have to draw it after onDraw is updated each time? onDraw updates every frame so every time it's called shouldn't I draw the trail?

Comment: mm take a look at the code below, to see if we are talking about the same thing (i'm writing it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to have the character and its trail independently calculated:

**Basic Solution**

```
Path mCharacterPath=new Path();


public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

      canvas.drawBitmap (mCharacter, mPosX, mPosY, mCharacterPaint);
      canvas.drawPath (mCharacterPath, mPathPaint);

}

public void add_point_to_path(int x, int y) {
       mPath.lineTo(x,y);
}
```

So every some time, you just call

```
add_point_to_path (mPosX, mPosY);
```

and it will add the current sprite position to the path.

Changing the mPathPaint you can customize the kind of path, as you can guess. Also, you can add arcs, curves, etc...

**BEtter solution**

Another solution is to create a bitmap, transparent, below everything:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


     // we draw our auxiliary bitmap that contains all the trails
     canvas.drawBitmap (mTransparentBitmapForTrails, 0, 0, mTransparentBitmapPaint);
     .
     // then we draw the usual stuff, characters, etc...
     canvas.drawBitmap (mCharacterBimap, mPosX, mPosY, mCharacterPaint);
     .
     .
} 

// this creates a transparent background the size of the screen
// you will render trails here and they all will be painted at once in onDraw below the craracters

Bitmap mBitmapForTrails;
Canvas mCanvasForTrails;

public void initializeBitmapForTrails() {
      mBitmapForTrails=new Bitmap(); // checkout how to create bitmaps with specific w&h, can't remember at the moment. 
      mCanvasForTrails=new Canvas(mBitmapForTrails); // we create a canvas to draw in that bitmap
}

// this will paint the trail in our secondary bitmap. This secondary bitmap doesn't get
// erased, so the drawTrail()'s are accumulative

public void drawTrail (int x, int y) {
   mCanvasForTrails.drawBitmap(your_cool_trail_bitmap, x, y, mTrailPaint);
   invalidate(); // this works, but for performance you'll later do invalidate(rect), so Android only repaints the changed portion of the bitmap. That rect will be the rectangle occupied by the trail bitmap. ie. (x,y,x+trailw,y+trialh)
}
```

so you will paint all the trails to that bitmap. This has the advantage that the paths can be very complex without affecting performance at all.

Comment: What if I were to want mCharacterPaint to be an image or a bitmap? Is that possible?

Comment: mCharactedPaint is the paint object, with it you control thins like the alpha, stroke width, etc ... the actual bitmap is mCharacterBitmap

Comment: So the mCharacterBitmap is the one being drawn upon? As for the trail, is that just an arbitrary line that has a width, stroke and alpha? I want the bitmap to be the actual trail for the sprite that is animating down the screen. Doesn't this draw a path behind the sprite, but as a line object with distinct paint characteristics?

Comment: I think the second solution is what you need. Yep, the first one just draws a character then a path as a line. The second one, you can draw whatever you want as trail. You just create a transparent auxiliar bitmap the size of the screen, that will be always drawn behind the character. Then, you can arbitrareily paint lines, sprites or whatever you want to that bitmap (using another canvas, see initializeBitmapForTrails).

Comment: For the mTransparentBitmapForTrails object, is that bitmap going to be the same height and width as the screen?

Comment: yup. this way you can draw unlimited trails there for any character position!

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to where you would call the drawTrail() method. Would the method be called after you draw the transparent bitmap in the onDraw method?

Comment: You will call drawTrail whenever your character's coordinates change, to add a trail there, then the view will be invalidated and onDraw will be called by Android and your bitmap trail (containing all the trails you drawTrail'ed in the past) will be rendered. Check it out, it's easier to try it than to explain

Comment: For the invalidate() call, it is saying something about 'only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views'. Does that mean that invalidate() is being called in the wrong place? Currently I have it being called at the end of drawTrail().

Comment: invalidate() can in fact only be called from the UI thread. If you are calling it from other thread (looks like, but I wonder which one, u using a 3rd party lib or something?) just call "postInvalidate()". This will correctly call invalidate from the UI thread.

Comment: It's easier if I show you the class. http://pastebin.com/bqFjSVXT.
I'm calling it from within a class called GameView that extends SurfaceView.

Comment: Here's the entire source code if you need more context. http://www.sourcepod.com/bbzssa51-24265

Comment: you should call drawTrail() from your GameThread, more or less in the same place where you modify the character X & Y.

Comment: ohh .. to follow your structure, if you see, you are abstracting each paintable class TedSprite/TedSpriteBG into a class that draws itself onto GameView. It would be cool to follow that approach and create a TrailClass just like the TedSprite one so you could also do on onDraw : trails.draw(canvas). Or you could move the trail logic inside TedSprite class. There's a lot of stuff going on there! you have a "pro" game structure but I bet you don't understand very well all the parts involved until the final picture is rendered. SurfaceView deserves a big read!

Comment: You are a 100% right that I don't understand all the tiny parts that are going on. I attempted to make a TrailClass before but when it was drawn on screen it never permanently drew a trail or moved from it's initial position on screen. I believed the problem to have generated from the onDraw method since it redraws everything on screen.

Comment: ok so try to migrate the logic I proposed into that class. If you got it to draw a trail, you have all the necessary parts! Substitute that trail you were able to draw for the bitmap. Then you can paint all the trails from onDraw (trails.paint(canvas)) and also add trails from anywhere (trails.add(x,y)) . This "anywhere" will be 99% TedSprite. So: TedSprite updates, adds a trail, then in the onDraw cycle trails will be rendered, and ted too.

Comment: If I migrate the logic, won't conflicts arise because of the invalidate() call?

Comment: nah you won't use invalidate then, I didn't realized you were using suraceview. Just do one TrailClass like Ted's , only this class has inside the Bitmap for trails and the method for adding a new trail. Then from onDraw you will paint it.

Comment: By the onDraw, you mean the onDraw in the TedSprite class, right?

Comment: hahah lots of onDraws! isnt there? You can paint it from both ondraws, it's up to you where you think it makes more sense. If only Ted's gonna draw trails, then why not, you draw the trails from Ted's onDraw class. But if you reuse the Trail class so anything in your game can paint trails, you then paint the trails just like you paint ted from the main onDraw call. In any case, Ted would separately call addTrail. In the latter case, Ted and any other character will call addTrail, but only main onDraw will render the Trails bitmap.

Comment: I'm a tad bit confused. Here is my TedSprite class after I implemented your logic. http://pastebin.com/FnSExhuu
At this point, the trail is not being drawn on screen. Did you mean that I should implement an entirely new class called Trail and then implement it within the TedSprite class?

Comment: Hmmm. I implemented the logic inside the TedSprite class correctly and the trail isn't even being drawn on screen once. Could this be a problem with how the Bitmaps and Canvases are being defined? The program isn't crashing but the trail bitmap isn't even being drawn on screen once. Could this problem possibly be generated by the GamemView onDraw method that is drawing the map bitmap over and over again? Could that be possibly drawing over the trail?

Comment: there's a typo on the pastebin class. There's 2 bitmapfortrails, have you seen? delete the     private Bitmap mTransparentBitmapForTrails . Maybe that's the problem!

Comment: Are you referring to the TedSprite class having two mBitmapForTrails?

Comment: yess only one is correct, the one where you draw the stuff to.. I corrected it here http://pastebin.com/FHTSadGt

Comment: For this code correction, were you referring to the implementation of the new class Trail or the logic being done within the TedSprite class. I corrected the error and provided only one mBitmapForTrails object(removed the mTransparentBitmapForTrails and defined mBitmapForTrails) and the trail is still not even appearing on once. I'm sorry to keep harassing you but I look at this and think it should work but it doesn't.

Comment: all of them, it's a typo for writing stuff very fast. yes I also think it should work, but is very late over here, 5am, maybe tomorrow I see it clear :) keep doing experiments, I think you're really close to get it done!

Comment: Hey I finally got it to work! Thank you so much for the help! It turns out I was passing an incorrect field for the mBitmapForTrails variable and it was drawing on screen properly. Now I'm off to try and find a way to scroll down the screen and draw bitmaps one after another. Thanks again so much for the help. You truly represent the best aspects of humanity.

Comment: Another quick question. If you use canvas.translate to move down the screen, will you have to keep redrawing a new bitmap as soon as the old one is passed to keep the trail appearing on screen?

Comment: i don't understand your question very well... If you mean to compensate for the translation, the usual thing is to do canvas.save() , then translate to paint etc, then canvas.restore() to compensate for all modifications so the next iteration has the same starting conditions (but dont know if this is related to your question :P

Comment: Alright I'll explain it better. If you have a character moving down the screen and the canvas translating as well, the canvas will eventually be in a position where the bitmap is eventually not shown anymore. How would you be able to draw a bitmap after the next one in succession so that the character appears to be moving down the bitmap endlessly?

Comment: aha so you have kind of a background scroll behind the character and want to paint another one. I suppose as the character moves down, the background moves up, and you need to paint another background ? is it that?

Comment: Yes it's exactly that. The character needs to appear to be scrolling down the screen and eventually the bitmap(the background) will be populated with objects.

Comment: ok so you need at least 2 backgrounds :) to make an endless effect. You'll render one after another. When the first background exits the screen completely, will be at the same time that the second background covers the whole screen. Then you just move the first background to the bottom and repeat the cycle. This is efficient with 2 3 or 4 backgrounds, but if you need more (i mean, kind of the map being different everytime) you'd have to switch to a tile-based approach. This is how 90% of scrolling games are coded.

Comment: If the canvas translates to the point where the first bitmap is cut off, would the bitmap of the second be drawn at the translate's coordinates? More specifically, If I did canvas.translate(x, y), would the bitmap that I draw after I have translated to the end of the original bitmap be drawn at some value greater than or equal to that x and y, or will it be drawn at 0,0 like the original bitmap?

Comment: I suppose both approaches will work. The easiest maybe is, instead of translating, just drawing the background in negative offsets (-1 ... -height), and the next one (+height .... 0). Also, take a look at canvas.clipRect to define the part that is visible: This way the offscreen canvas won't be much of a performance hit.

Comment: Also just realized the "trailing algorithm" only works for the length of one bitmap! Have to figure out how to keep drawing the transparent bitmap to keep the trail going along with the animation. Thank you sincerely for the advice!

Comment: ohhh its true haha ... the transparent bitmap where you paint the trails is allocated for just a screen! If you need to keep the trail across unlimited screens I'm afraid the current trail logic won't be useful, you'll have to store key points to draw the trails independently, because it's not realistic to allocate "n" transparent bitmaps, you'll get an **OutOfMEmoryException** in 5 or 6 screens... The cleanest solution will be to change to a tile-based approach and just add a "trailed tile" to the map. Besides, it will also solve your scrolling problem

Comment: For a tile based approach, would I still be able to animate the sprite down the screen and be able to implement collision detection? I feel as though if I set everything to a tile, then the character sprite will have to be turned into a tile as well.

Comment: yeah, the tile would be independent from the background. The background is divided on tiles so you can store a "map" to create a nearly infinite background without consuming all the memory. For example, to do a sea, you'd barely need 10 tiles, that you can combine & repeat a 1,000,000 x 1,000,000 pixels bitmap. Without tiles, that bitmap alone will require 100Mb. With tiles, you just store one tile code per 256 or 512 sq. pixels.

Comment: the character is already a "tile", but is independent from the map. To draw the trails, I suppose you'd have to define "trailed tiles", so when the character has ever been in one tile, you change that tile code to its dirty version. Might be trickier to replicate the trail exactly, but you get huge benefits and flexibility.